# Indefinite Integral $ \int \frac {1}{\cos x + \cot^2 x}\mathrm dx $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$ \int \frac {1}{\cos x + \cot^2 x}\mathrm dx $$
I have tried things like trying to bring terms to the numerator so that they would cancel out with a trig sub but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Are you sure the integrand is correct? It seems rather messy to me.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha throws up an awful mess. The result is elementary though.

Comment: @benmcgloin yes it is correct

Comment: Then to do this by hand would be extremely tedious, I recommend using Wolfram as Trebor has suggested.

Comment: @Trebor I have seen the answer on WolframAlpha. The main objective of this question is the method of solution. Also, sometimes WolframAlpha seems to spit out a complicated mess when the solution can be simpler.

Comment: @Trebor. Very simple in fact ! There is no CAS being the $\alpha$ and the $\omega$; here is a proof. Cheers :-)

Comment: The command of Matematica `Integrate[1/(Cos[x] + Cot[x]^2), x]` performs $$-2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{5 \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{5}+3\right) \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2 \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)}}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2}{5} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{5}-3\right) \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2 \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)}}\right)-\log \left(\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+\log \left(\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) .$$

Comment: I think the Weierstrass substitution (i.e. $t=\tan(x/2)$) and partial fractions works.

Comment: @projectilemotion I will try it out

Comment: @AaryaBhatt Can you tell where is this integral from? JEE?

Comment: @Algebrology This has no significant origin. It is a random question from a fellow student.

Comment: @AaryaBhatt ah ok, just a hint(I guess so), can you write $\cos x$ in terms of $\tan x$? if you can write it like that then Weierstrass substitution works, as pointed out by projectile motion

Comment: @projectilemotion Yes, it does work.

Comment: Also, try to evaluate the integral $$\int \frac{1}{\cos x + \cot x}\mathrm{dx}$$

Comment: @Algebrology already done that...